# Not able to find JAVA in schroot

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, java-7, android-source, chroot, schroot

I am trying compile AOSP code using schroot in ubuntu 18.04 64 bit.

Not able to find java in schroot.

$java -version
bash: java: command not found

If I open another terminal and enter java version command its working. like below

java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the jdkX repo synced in? AOSP provides the prebuilts, for android 10, it is jdk9. For example, if I run the following command I get openjdk9:

```
. build/envsetup.sh && lunch aosp_blueline-userdebug

which java && java --version
```

Output:

```
prebuilts/jdk/jdk9/linux-x86/bin/java
openjdk 9
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9+181-android4685155)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181-android4685155, mixed mode)
```

Try running your java commands after lunch.